# How to export datatable copy with original source format .i.e same style, background color

Tags: php, jquery

How to export datatable copy with original source format .i.e same style ,background color
I want to export datatable into excel,pdf with original datatable format i.e. row color, column color or some rows are highlighted with yellow color 
for showing duplication to edit and update necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

For the PDF style you should add the `customize` attribute when you initialize the datatable, for example:

```
$('#your-table').DataTable( {
  buttons: [{
   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   title: 'My title',
   customize: function(doc) {
     doc.styles.title = {
       color: 'red',
       fontSize: '40',
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'center'
     }
     doc.styles.tableHeader = {
       color: 'red',
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
     doc.styles.tableBodyEven = {
       background: 'yellow',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
     doc.styles.tableBodyOdd = {
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
    doc.styles.tableFooter = {
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
   }  
 }]
})
```

Comment: i want show only specific row to show styles not for entire sheet , only some of the rows which are background color is yellow

Comment: Just set the styles you want in the customize section and thats it